# All mail sent by Postfix is received as spam

Tags: debian, postfix

I have a dedicated server on Server4You. The machine has Debian 7.8 and Plesk 11.5.30.

On the server I have  2 web sites , each with its respective IP address.

The problem is that all mail I send is received as SPAM, worse, in the accounts of Outlook do not even get emails.

**My DNS Reverse in Power Panel of Server4you is: mail.gupropiedades.cl for IP  69.64.49.24**

This is my DNS settings PLESK:

[image: Plesk]

Postfix: master.cf

```
 #smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    localhost:smtp  inet n - n - - smtpd
    69.64.49.24:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=mail.gupropiedades.cl
    209.126.115.118:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=mail.evaluandome.org
    #smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
    #smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    #dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
    #tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
    submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    #smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    #  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
    #  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
    #  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    #628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
    pickup fifo n - - 60 1 pickup
    cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
    qmgr fifo n - n 1 1 qmgr
    #qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
    tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
    rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman unix - n n - - pipe flags=R user=list:list argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}


plesk_virtual unix - n n - - pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames
plesk_saslauthd unix y y y - 1 plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/plesk/passwd.db
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

69.64.49.24- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=69.64.49.24 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

submission inet n - - - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination

209.126.115.118- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=209.126.115.118 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4
                                                                                                                                                      124,1         Bot
```

Main.cf

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = eagle354.startdedicated.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.startdedicated.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 69.64.49.24/32
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
non_smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

Testing of mail server: mail.gupropiedades.cl

[image]

Mail received as SPAM for a user.

```
Delivered-To: tankehack@gmail.com
Received: by 10.180.7.166 with SMTP id k6csp2219431wia;
        Fri, 3 Apr 2015 20:58:25 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.42.133.71 with SMTP id g7mr7474120ict.15.1428119905135;
        Fri, 03 Apr 2015 20:58:25 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <contacto@gupropiedades.cl>
Received: from eagle354.startdedicated.com (mail.gupropiedades.cl. [69.64.49.24])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 5si8751753ioj.32.2015.04.03.20.58.24
        for <tankehack@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 03 Apr 2015 20:58:25 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of contacto@gupropiedades.cl designates 69.64.49.24 as permitted sender) client-ip=69.64.49.24;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of contacto@gupropiedades.cl designates 69.64.49.24 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=contacto@gupropiedades.cl
Received: from webmail.evaluandome.org (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by eagle354.startdedicated.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6D15941E79
    for <tankehack@gmail.com>; Sat,  4 Apr 2015 03:58:24 +0000 (UTC)
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1;  q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=default; d=gupropiedades.cl;
  b=SdEMBq9IY+Tz6uaz70kopEX29iETl9OEP3gzlHzJqpGSR1WklbYtZW2v+V+pd2w/t7s69pyve9tK4Rn28xCLtpKVDRt3hdt353j2t+CHALmCw9QwGEFjYeNugVaLDOYRSuvW/qqN5YMGFskB0S0TCGnKDllzDsmZRwVqh3mNZ2U=;
  h=MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Date:From:To:Subject:Message-ID:X-Sender:User-Agent;
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2015 00:58:24 -0300
From: Contacto Gupropiedades <contacto@gupropiedades.cl>
To: tankehack@gmail.com
Subject: test
Message-ID: <4764a4c202b419ebfa2a1faac89938ea@gupropiedades.cl>
X-Sender: contacto@gupropiedades.cl
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9.5

testing mail server
```

Comment: You should fix your hostname to be `mail.gupropiedades.cl` (look at the Received: header). I'd guess that's the `myhostname` in your `main.cf`, but I'm not sure (I run exim).

Comment: @derobert I already did what you said but the problem persists

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is, looking very closely at those headers, there should be `dkim=pass` in the `Authentication-Results` header if your DKIM signature is working. It's not there, so for some reason it's probably not working.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. Can you think of something to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Just after you make sure your DKIM is working properly:**

I had the exact same issue. Every test was ok, just like you. The problem was the self signed SSL certificate used to send email.

If you check your server logs while send an email to a gmail address you'll get something like "untrusted connection". Apparently gmail etc doesn't like this.

One day I decided to replace the self signed certificate with a legit one and suddenly no more spam on Gmail etc. It has been working fine for a long time.

I'm using a free let's encrypt certificate on that server and it works. But there are some things you need to check in order for it to work:

1. Install let's encrypt in your machine:

   ```
   cd /etc/ssl/certs
   openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096
   cd ~
   git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt && cd letsencrypt
   ```
2. Generate a sandalone SSL for your server hostname:

   ```
   (stop all web servers)
   cd ~/letsencrypt
   ./letsencrypt-auto --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory auth -d host.domain.dev
   ```
3. Add let's encrypt intermediate certificate to your system;
4. Postfix requires the certificate as:

   ```
   smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs        
   smtpd_tls_key_file = privkey.pem
   smtpd_tls_cert_file = cert.pem
   smtpd_tls_CAfile = chain.pem
   ```

Always check postfix log `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` when sending an email to make sure everything was right. If it is you should see: `Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in`. If something fails postfix will complain about untrusted connection / not finding the certificate, CA etc.

**PS**: Maybe you should try EXIM, usually big providers like it a lot more then Postfix in terms of SPAM.